# Disable link button in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, button

I used link buttons in my site. At Starting the "Delete" button should disable. After     click "Add" button it will be enable. But I cant achieve. I don't know what mistake i made. Any one Please correct ?

```
enter code here

if ($('.' + inputContainerCss).length < 3) {
    //    if ($('.' + inputContainerCss).length < 2) {
    $('#' + btnDelId).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}

  $('#' + btnAddId).click(function () {
    var num = $('.' + inputContainerCss).length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    var newNum = new Number(num + 1);   // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

    // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
    var newElem = $('#' + inputContainerIdPrefix + num).clone().attr('id', inputContainerIdPrefix + newNum);

    // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
    //newElem.children(':first').attr('id', firstChildInputIdPrefix + newNum).attr('name', firstChildInputIdPrefix + newNum);


    newElem.children().each(function () {
        var idPrefix = $(this).attr('id').substring(0, $(this).attr('id').length - 1);
        var namePrefix = $(this).attr('name').substring(0, $(this).attr('name').length - 1);
        $(this).attr('id', idPrefix + newNum).attr('name', namePrefix + newNum);
    })

    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
    $('#' + inputContainerIdPrefix + num).after(newElem);

    // enable the "remove" button
    $('#' + btnDelId).attr('disabled', '');
```

Comment: Could you give us more details about your usecase? What are you doing and what you want to get?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? It the button initially disabled? Can't you enable it? Or doesn't it work to make him disabled again after removing elements? Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: The button is always disable only. I want to enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not your coding Issue. You have to add some jquery files for this like,

[Just clik the link and download it.](http://jquery.com/download/)